# Populate html text in shiny with a list of variables created on server.R

Tags: html, r, shiny, server-side

I would like to use a list() generated on server.r to populate a paragraph in ui.r

server.r

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    output$out <- reactive({
        list(
            a = 'brown',
            b = 'quick',
            c = 'lazy'
        )
    })
})
```

ui.r

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    p('The ', output$out$a, output$out$b, 'fox jumps over the ', output$out$c, 'dog')
))
```

I know that the code is not correct and you have to use helper functions to access data in ui.r, but I just wanted to illustrate my problem.

Comment: see `?renderUI`

Comment: thank you. actually I was hoping for a solution that allows me to leave the static part of the sentence on ui.r. With renderUI you suggest to build the entire sentence in server.r isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I'm not understanding your intent, but have a look at this:

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output) {
  out <- reactive({

    tmp <- list()
    tmp <- list(
      a = 'brown',
      b = 'quick',
      c = 'lazy'
    )

    return(tmp)
  })

  output$a <- function() {
    out()[[1]]
  }

  output$b <- function() {
    out()[[2]]
  }

  output$c <- function() {
    out()[[3]]
    }
}

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  p('The ', textOutput("a"), textOutput("b"),
    'fox jumps over the ', textOutput("c"), 'dog')
))

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Yep, I hoped for a cleaner solution, creating only 1 output object instead of many different ones. But reading around I understood that either I do as you say or I produce the entire string in the server.r and then pass it onto ui.R, no other shortcuts.

Comment: Here are some additional examples that might be helpful if you wish to pursue a more advanced solution: 
creating UI objects using a loop, https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/creating-a-ui-from-a-loop.html
list of reactive values, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43107978/accessing-reactivevalues-in-a-reactivevaluestolist